# How to copy FAR file manager's output

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, far-manager

[image: ping output in far file manager]
Hi guys, how do I copy FAR-Manager's console output? For example when I use ping command I want to copy it's output text, but not image.

Oh, and I would like to do so with keyboard! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do it the same way for all Windows Console programs:

1. Enter *Mark* mode: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>
2. Mark text using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

---

Alternatively, you can redirect the output of a specific command to a file:

```
ping > output.txt
```

Comment: Or `ping | clip` to actually copy the output.

Comment: this is also good, but instead of Alt+Space, E, K it's shorter to use Alt+Insert :)

Comment: ping | clip does not work for me :(

Comment: @ViliusK Which OS you were on? `clip.exe` first appeared in Vista.

Answer (score 19):

Far Manager has a special key combination that starts the selection: `Alt+Insert`. Then follow steps 2 and 3 suggested by @grawity.

Comment: Alt+Insert is what I was looking for. Thank's Roman! :)

Comment: *Far Manager* has a lot of useful predefined key combinations. But many of them are not quite discoverable (not included into menus, command bars, etc.), so take a look at the built-in help: F1 | Keyboard reference.

Comment: Alternatively look at docs online: https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/master/far/FarEng.hlf.m4

Comment: I'm using FAR manager for over 14 years, and I haven't known about this feature. Thank you so much, it seems like the only way to select text when running on windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

in the far console, type

`edit:<ping 127.0.0.1`

instead of just

`ping 127.0.0.1`

it will execute the ping command and open the Far built-in editor with the output afterwards. You will be able to edit it as a normal text file

you can also use `view:<` instead of `edit:<` to open the built-in viewer, not editor

Answer (score 0):

**Hotkeys and scrolling during running command:** you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open history of output in built-in viewer or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to open it in built-in editor. This allows efficient commands output investigation, including scrolling possibility, using built-in viewer and editor capabilities.

From [internal help](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/blob/master/far2l/bootstrap/scripts/FarEng.hlf.m4)