# Far Manager how to export file names list from Temporary panel

Tags: far-manager

I have ALT+F7 (file mask + Containing text)-> [Panel] search results in "Temporary Panel".
I need to copy filenames (with path) from the "Temporary Panel" to text file.

the first options is to copy output the way explained in [How to copy FAR file manager's output](https://superuser.com/questions/235651/how-to-copy-far-file-managers-output)
This options only works for short file names and if results fit one screen.

the second options is to click ALT+Enter in each file name for copying the file name to command line one by one.
This option is not really comfortable if you have too many files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the files that you want to copy (e.g. numpad <kbd>*</kbd>), press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy the filenames including paths.

If you don't select files, only the filename of the "active" file is copied.

---

Other useful shortcuts:

```
Ctrl+Ins
Copy names of the selected files to clipboard (if the command line is empty).

Ctrl+Shift+Ins
Copy names of the selected files to clipboard.

Alt+Shift+Ins
Copy full names of selected files to clipboard.

Ctrl+Alt+Ins
Copy real names of selected files to clipboard.


Ctrl+Shift+C
Copy the selected files to clipboard.

Ctrl+Shift+X
Cut the selected files to clipboard.
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!